# MySQL LOAD DATA - Avoid convert string to zero when integer column

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I try to trigger an error when I load a string into integer column with LOAD DATA.

The string value in file (aaa) become "0" in table.

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE (
  a INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  b INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  c VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  c VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

My loader :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' 
INTO TABLE `test1` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (a,b,c,d)
```

My data file :

```
a;b;c;d
aaa;11;aa;z
2;bbb;bb;x
3;33;cc;w
4;44;dd;y
```

And the result in the table :

```
a   b   c   d
-------------
0   11  aa  z    
2   0   bb  x
3   33  cc  w
4   44  dd  y
```

You can see that "aaa" become "0" and "bbb" too.
I would like the file records to be rejected.

I tried to set sql mode to STRICT_ALL_TABLES but no effect :

```
set sql_mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES;
```

Thank you !